# CUDA By Example utility libraries

Tags: cuda

I'm currently studying the CUDA by Example book and I'm actually writing the Julia Set example. I'm new to CUDA programming.

But there is something that maybe I've missed : where do I find the `book.h` and `cpu_bitmap.h`  headers ? Is there a link somewhere to download them or a way to get them and get the code working ?

In the book, this is written :

```
#include "../common/cpu_bitmap.h"
```

Where may I get this file ?

I'm on Mac OS X Mountain Lion platform.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 5):

Just got this book out the library, found all the source code here:

https://bitbucket.org/mrfright/cuda_by_example/src

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/snp-gpgpu/source/browse/trunk/f/common/?r=4

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @RobertRyan Thank you for your advice. Since the other answer appears to describe the essential parts of this problem. Is that OK I don't repeat that here? Or should I just delete this answer and make it a comment? I will be aware to provide enough information in my answer from now on.

Comment: No problem. Just a suggestion for future answers. A little context will help people understand your responses a lot better. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I have copied the code from code.google in a book.h file. It gives me many errors :
exit : Type "exit" could not be resolved.
Function "rand()" could not be resolved.
pthread_create, pthread_join,  pthread_cancel : all three functions get "could not be resolved" error.
Why does it not work ?

Comment: @Pierre-LucDelisle Did you include all correspond header files? for example you need #include "stdlib.h" to use exit.

Comment: <stdlib.h>, <stddef.h>, <stdio.h>, namespace std, <math.h>, <pthread.h> are all included in the book.h file.
gl_helper works fine.
glx.h, which I copied from the Internet, has errors : X11/Xlib.h and X11/Xutil.h get the "unresolved inclusion" error. I have imported in my project the files from /usr/X11 and /usr/X11R6, but these two header files still cannot be found.

Comment: I didn't know this book was so hard to make it working. For CUDA-Only programs, it's fine, but as soon as you want to make a bitmap (I want to run the Julia Set), everything starts to be complicated when it should not be !

Comment: Oh and yes #include "stdlib.h" is also in my book.h file and exit() function is still not recognized.

Comment: @Pierre-LucDelisle Sorry but I don't have Mac to do the test. I tried to use nvcc to compile a simple sample with book.h from the site and it works find here. So unless I know more about your environment I can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you download whole CUDA_by_Example, it should have common directory in it. anytime you want to include the head files in that directory, you have to let the compiler know the correct path of them.

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2015 the [official page for CUDA by Example](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-example) has moved to https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-example from where you can download the sample chapter and example code including `book.h` and `cpu_bitmap.h`.

Answer (score 0):

The NVIDIA site has source code for the entire book in a zip file. 
https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/cuda_by_example.zip